# Wrong sorting parameter in documentation for question/{ids}/answers

Tags: support, bug, api, documentation, sort

It looks like that in the [question/{ids}/answers](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-questions) documentation, there is a mistake:

> votes – score

Shouldn't this be

> votes – votes

Answer (score 1):

No, I think this is intentional. The word on the left side is the value of the `sort` parameter:

[image]

while the word on the right side is a field name of the [answer object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/answer):

[image]